# How to remove Microsoft AutoUpdate from macOS?

Tags: macos, auto-update

I tried Microsoft Edge, but It installed "Microsoft AutoUpdate" app. Its very annoying that Microsoft installs crap I didn't want on my machine.

I tried to look for the Application but no luck. [image: microsoft crap]

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/1544338/turn-off-microsoft-apps-microsoft-autoupdate-app-on-a-mac

Answer (score 41, accepted):

I finally managed to find the Microsoft AutoUpdate.

You need to go to `/Library` directory, at the **root** of your HD, and search "Microsoft autoupdate" on that location (which finds `/Library/Application Support/Microsoft/MAU2.0/Microsoft AutoUpdate.app` on my system.

Then just move it to the trash.

[image]

Comment: There are quite a few places this can hide. Sometimes you need to remove office apps that will reinstall it when they run or narrow down [which version you have](https://macadmins.software/msupdate/)

Comment: Without this application, how do you expect to update the app?

Comment: You just download the new app when needed or check for updates within the top-dropdown menu as a normal user. You don't need Microsoft spying on you to keep your stuff up-to-date 

Comment: another way: https://osxdaily.com/2019/07/20/how-delete-microsoft-autoupdate-mac/

Comment: When you navigate to the directory you want. type `open .` and it will display the Finder.

Comment: I annoy about this for 2 years, thanks for release me sir.

Answer (score 8):

If you are a cli person, this should suffice:

```bash
sudo rm -rf "/Library/Application Support/Microsoft/MAU2.0/Microsoft AutoUpdate.app"
sudo rm -rf "/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.microsoft.autoupdate.helper.plist"
sudo rm -rf "/Library/LaunchAgents/com.microsoft.update.agent.plist"
sudo rm -rf "/Library/PrivilegedHelperTools/com.microsoft.autoupdate.helper"
```

Comment: I usually recommend to just use `sudo rm -r /...` so you get an error message if something goes wrong.

Answer (score 2):

In case you're using macOS Ventura you need to delete:

1. The Microsoft AutoUpdate.app app located in `/Library/Application Support/Microsoft/MAU2.0`
2. The `com.microsoft.update.agent.plist` agent located in `/Library/LaunchAgents`
3. The `com.microsoft.autoupdate.helper.plist` daemon located in `/Library/LaunchDaemons`

To delete them from Terminal, run

```
sudo rm -rf /Library/Application\ Support/Microsoft/MAU2.0
sudo rm /Library/LaunchAgents/com.microsoft.update.agent.plist
sudo rm /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.microsoft.autoupdate.helper.plist
```

[Source](https://mattkomarnicki.com/articles/how-to-completely-remove-microsoft-autoupdate-from-macos-ventura)

Comment: Basically the same as [answered by Mehmet](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/459961/371189). Only valuable addition is the linked article.

Answer (score 1):

To clean uninstall it:

1. Install the great free and small app
   [AppCleaner](https://freemacsoft.net/appcleaner/)
2. Open Finder, press <kbd>Cmd Shift G</kbd>, and paste `/Library/Application Support/Microsoft/MAU2.0/`
3. You will find "Microsoft AutoUpdate.app", drag it to `AppCleaner`
4. Click Remove

There may be some unchecked boxes I suggest to not check (because they may relate to other Microsoft apps).

For more experienced users, visit these three locations using Finder's <kbd>Cmd Shift G</kbd> shortcut:

1. `/Library/LaunchAgents`, drag `com.microsoft.update.agent.plist` to the
   Trash
2. `/Library/LaunchDaemons`, drag `com.microsoft.autoupdate.helper.plist` to the Trash
3. `/Library/PrivilegedHelperTools`, drag
   `com.microsoft.autoupdate.helper.plist` to the Trash

Answer (score 1):

I ended up with this. Run it as a single line in Terminal app.

Prevent AutoUpdater to be re-installed:
`for F in /Library/{PrivilegedHelperTools,Launch{Agents,Daemons}}/com.microsoft.*update*.plist /Library/Application\ Support/Microsoft/MAU* ~/Library/Microsoft/*Updater; do echo 'Processing '"${F}"'..'; sudo rm -rf "${F}" && sudo mkdir "${F}" && sudo chflags uchg "${F}"; done`

[image]

In case if you wish to revert that later and allow AutoUpdater:
`for F in /Library/{PrivilegedHelperTools,Launch{Agents,Daemons}}/com.microsoft.*update*.plist /Library/Application\ Support/Microsoft/MAU* ~/Library/Microsoft/*Updater; do echo 'Processing '"${F}"'..'; sudo rm -rf "${F}"; done`

It is removing AutoUpdater folders, creating empty ones and locking them via `chflags uchg` command, Microsoft apps can't handle that.