# How do I disable and delete Microsoft Auto Updater for Office:mac 2016?

Tags: ms-office

I now using a 2024 MacBookPro on Sonoma 14.4 I set up using Migration Assistant.   On my 2019 MacBook Pro I had installed a purchased suite Microsoft Office Home & Student 2016 . This program migrated over, but when I tried to use it, it would not accept my product key.  The MS rep had me delete the suite and reinstall a download from my MS account.  On my 2019, I was never prompted for updates.

Since then I have not been able to get the auto update prompt from continually prompting me to check for updates.  The rep was also had me check some box not to update when installing the program.  I have also disabled MS items from running in login items - but this has had no effect on the updater.

How can I disable & delete the updater?

Edit:  I saw similar posts re: my same issue but I did not have folder or files mentioned in those articles. This: [older article](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/428234/how-to-remove-microsoft-autoupdate-from-macos)  was not applicable, I could not find these files.

[image: auto update pic]

Comment: Have you searched (using Spotlight or the Finder) for "Microsoft AutoUpdate" ? And here's a [related question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/428234/how-to-remove-microsoft-autoupdate-from-macos).

Comment: I don’t have that MAU2.0 file, or those directories.

Comment: so I have been unable to find MAU2.0 files, etc using the traditional finder search with all search locations enabled.  However, I used find any file app and found them all.  This update problem solved.  I dont know why Apple changed whats visible in search - even the finder, go, option & then library would not show the files.  I had to click on location, then Macintosh hd, then library and search....

Comment: Glad you found a solution!